# What's the best practice: Using queryBuilders or creating table view?

Tags: php, postgresql, phalcon

I use Phalcon which has it's own **query builder**: https://olddocs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.0/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Query_Builder.html

and PostgreSQL where I create table **views** that joins complicated queries to one table which next is represented in PHP as a **TableModelClass**.

**My question is:** what's the best practice, creating views and then reperesent it in **TableModelClass** or using query builder for joining tables?

What are the pros and cons of using both methods?

For example when I use view I can also add aditional **WHERE** on it and generate more specified results. So for me that's better way, but I'm not sure if its the best.

I read on the internet (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151169/are-views-harmful-for-performance-in-postgresql) that **views** are not slower than normal query and that means that query sended by **query builder** has this same speed in geting results?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would have to find out.

I have found performance increase in using sql queries and using the database connection to fetch results and written this into my model.

I guess the advantage of doing this might be that it makes your model code a little more portable if you are using basic syntax.